# How to subtract a date with current date to get how long since it happened?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, date, datetime

I get a date from a RSS FEED **JSON** file , the date is something like "**2018-02-09 00:00:00**" , It's a string but I know that I can turn it into integer using `Number()`  or `parseInt()` and get the date with `Date()` , I want to get the time passed since it happened , Like 1 day ago , 2 hours ago .. etc , How to achieve that ?

Comment: which part of your code are you having trouble with

Comment: @JaromandaX I can't get what I want , for example if I tried Date() - the date after converted it into a number , I get NAN (not a number)

Comment: `Date() - the date after converted to number` - this doesn't look like javascript

Comment: Date() - Number(dateFromJsonFile)

Comment: and what does `dateFromJsonFile` look like - "2018-02-09 00:00:00"? - `console.log(Number("2018-02-09 00:00:00"))` results in `NaN` - you can't convert a random string into a Date value - first you need to convert that string into a date - but that format is not going to work consistently - I would recommend the moment.js library - you'll find it makes life easier

Comment: "2018-02-09 00:00:00" has no timezone, so will likely (but not certainly) be parsed as local, so it represents a different moment in time in each timezone with a different offset. It might be yesterday in one timezone and today in another.

Answer (score 0):

Credit to Robert Gravelle at https://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/javascript/calculating-the-difference-between-two-dates-in-javascript.html

**Calculating the Difference between Two Known Dates**

Unfortunately, calculating a date interval such as days, weeks, or months between two known dates is not as easy because you can't just add Date objects together. In order to use a Date object in any sort of calculation, we must first retrieve the Date's internal millisecond value, which is stored as a large integer. The function to do that is Date.getTime(). Once both Dates have been converted, subtracting the later one from the earlier one returns the difference in milliseconds. The desired interval can then be determined by dividing that number by the corresponding number of milliseconds. For instance, to obtain the number of days for a given number of milliseconds, we would divide by 86,400,000, the number of milliseconds in a day (1000 x 60 seconds x 60 minutes x 24 hours):

```
Date.daysBetween = function( date1, date2 )
{
    //Get 1 day in milliseconds
    var one_day=1000*60*60*24;

    // Convert both dates to milliseconds
    var date1_ms = date1.getTime();
    var date2_ms = date2.getTime();

    // Calculate the difference in milliseconds
    var difference_ms = date2_ms - date1_ms;

    // Convert back to days and return
    return Math.round(difference_ms/one_day); 
}

//Set the two dates
var y2k  = new Date(2000, 0, 1); 
var Jan1st2010 = new Date(y2k.getFullYear() + 10, y2k.getMonth(),     y2k.getDate());
var today= new Date();
//displays 726
console.log( 'Days since ' 
       + Jan1st2010.toLocaleDateString() + ': ' 
       + Date.daysBetween(Jan1st2010, today));
```

The rounding is optional, depending on whether you want partial days or not.

Answer (score 0):

First we define the desired units of time (conversions from milliseconds):

```
timeTypes={ year: 1000*60*60*24*365, month: 1000*60*60*24*30, day: 1000*60*60*24, hour: 1000*60*60, minute: 1000*60, second: 1000, millisecond: 1 };
```

Start with `td` being the time difference in milliseconds, the result of `Date` object `.getTime()` values:

```
td = d1.getTime() - d2.getTime();
```

And then we reduce it by the largest units and build a string as we go:

```
timeString='';
remaining=td;
for (i in timeTypes)
    if (remaining > timeTypes[i]) {
        count = parseInt(remaining/timeTypes[i]);
        remaining -= timeTypes[i]*count;
        timeString += count+' '+i+(count>1 ? 's' : '')+' ';
    }
```

Now, `timeString` will contain something like:

```
1 month 9 days 42 seconds
```

This is treating every month as having 30 days, so that is a source of minor imprecision, but times less than a month are exact.